# Use a steel welding table to ground yourself from electrostatic discharge (ESD)?

Tags: ground, safety, esd, discharge, diy

I have a large steel welding table that I have been using as a work station to solder together my own custom PCBs.

I have been using my anti-electrostatic discharge grounding bracelet and connecting the alligator clip on the lead coming from it to my welding table.  I also have my MIG and TIG welders plugged into the wall but turned off, with the ground cables clamped to the welding table.

Am I right to assume that I am electrically effectively connecting my wrist to the ground of the circuit breaker panel in my workshop?

Any thoughts on this technique in general as a way to control ESD?

Any electrical schematics of a typical TIG or MIG welder, showing the grounding clamp connections?

Comment: You're right, you should be well and truly grounded and ESD shouldn't be a problem. Just don't try to power up any bare circuit boards on the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - I think that you will not have any ESD issues with the setup that you describe.

You may want to pick up a large sheet of conductive foam to put on top of your table for when you are working on circuit boards that might short out to the table.  We purchased a large package of high-resistivity conductive foam many years ago and are still using it for temporary table-top surfaces.  These are 3' x 4' sheets with a smooth surface that seems to wear very well.  I don't recall the exact amount of resistivity that it has but it was pretty high.

There are many grades of conductive foam available - some with low resistivity, some with high, some with a stable surface, some that starts to fall apart as soon as you look at it sideways.  But if you find the right stuff, it can make your life easier.